# How to use the Urls from firebase storage after uploading them in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Right now im using firebase storage and firebase database, my web app has 6 different products, everything is working fine in my code the only problem is that i have two buttons for uploading the product, the first button is upload files and it has this function :

```
      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const promises = []

            if (!files) return;


            Object.entries(files).map(([key, value]) => {

               const storageRef = ref(storage, `${selected}/${titulo}/${value.name}`);
               const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, value);
               promises.push(uploadTask)
               uploadTask.on("state_changed",
                   (snapshot) => {
                        const progress =
                           Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
                           setProgresspercent(progress);
                },
                (error) => {
                    alert(error);
                },
                async () => {
                    await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                        setURLs(prevState => [...prevState, downloadURL])
                    });

                },



            );



        })



        Promise.all(promises)

            .then(() =>
                toast.success('se subieron los archivos con exito', {
                    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
                })




            )
            .then(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

i have a state files that saves the files that were selected and then i map into them, and save the urls in a state called URLs, this code is working fine but then i have to press another button called add products to upload the product with the title, description,price  and images array with the urls i get from the previous function. i dont want to have two buttons to do this, instead i just want everything to be done in the function handleSubmit, but i cant get the urls after the mapping it says is empty, but when i use the second button then the urls are there, i dont know why i cant access the urls in the same function after mapping.

so my question is can i do this? can i add them to de database after the mapping and setting the urls? because whenever i try to do it is always empty

i tried console.log(urls) after mapping but is empty , and the console log is running before the mapping